# ARIMA model over- or underfitting: compare training and validation performance

Tags: modeling, arima, validation, overfitting

I'm doing research using seasonal and nonseasonal ARIMA models.
Here's the result of model identification:

[image]

Based on many sources,

> Your model is overfitting your training data when you see that the model performs well on the training data but does not perform well on the evaluation data.

So in my problem, is my model overfitting?

Comment: Which is your model?

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry I thought my model will overfitting. In fact my model already fine. Thanks for your concern :D